# Wrong Output in CS50 Pset2 Readability

Tags: c, cs50

The program uses the Coleman-Liau index. It is designed to output what (U.S.) grade level is needed to understand the text. The formula is:

index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8

When I enter simple text such as `hello there` I get a high grade level, but if I enter more complex text I get a lower grade level.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <cs50.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <math.h>

 float letter = 0;
 float word = 1;
 float sentence = 0;

 int main(void)
{
  string text = get_string("Text: ");

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
  {
      if ((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'))
      {
          letter++;
      }
      else if (text[i] == ' ')
      {
          word++;
      }
      else if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?')
      {
          sentence++;
      }
  }
  printf("Letter:%f, Word:%f, Sentence:%f\n", letter, word, sentence);

  float L = letter/word * 100;
  float S = sentence/word * 100;
  float x = (0.0588 * L) - (0.296 * S) - 15.8;
  if (x < 16 && x >= 0)
  {
      printf("Grade Level: %i",(int) round(x));
  }
  else if (x > 16)
  {
      printf("Grade Level: 16+");
  }
  else 
  {
      printf("Before Grade 1");
  }
```

Comment: If your input is `"hello there"`, then your code will count zero sentences. That can't be right, surely?

Comment: Indeed. When I am entering text ,  I am sure to use a '.' '!' or '?' to end sentences, as those are written to  be included in the program.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to count letters, you should check if the character is alphabetic or not. There is a built-in function in C for this (within ctype.h library)

```
isalpha() //the function returns non-zero if character is alphabetic.
```

To count words, you need to check if the character is blank or not. Within the same library, you could use the following function to check this.

```
isblank() //the function returns non-zero if character is blank.
```

Probably, your function where you count letters is not functioning right. I would print number of letters, words, sentences to see if your code behaves as normal. Then, calculate the index.